# Aplicativo consumindo muito recurso do servidor

Tags: java, android

Eu estou enfrentando um problema com um app em Java pra Android, o app aparentemente chega em um ponto que consome recurso excessivo do servidor, se muitos usuarios conectarem no app chega a ponto de derrubar o servidor, o app está em Java integrado com webservice em Laravel.

Abaixo vou postar a rotina que aparentemente causa problema pelo que detectamos no servidor, uma vez que essa rotina chama a url que detectamos estar consumindo recurso excessivo no servidor.

```
    private class UploadDataToServer extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            HttpParams myParams = new BasicHttpParams();

            myParams.setParameter("http.useragent", "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)");
            myParams.setIntParameter("http.socket.timeout", 60 * 1000);
            myParams.setBooleanParameter("http.connection.stalecheck", false);
            myParams.setIntParameter("http.connection.timeout", 60 * 1000);
            myParams.setBooleanParameter("http.protocol.handle-redirects", false);
            myParams.setIntParameter("http.socket.buffer-size", 8192);

            //HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(myParams, 100000); //100000
            //HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(myParams, 100000); //100000


            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(myParams);
            ResponseHandler<String> res = new BasicResponseHandler();
            HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost(
                    AndyConstants.ServiceType.UPDATE_PROVIDER_LOCATION);
            // HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest();
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(
                    AndyConstants.Params.ID, id));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(
                    AndyConstants.Params.TOKEN, token));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(
                    AndyConstants.Params.LATITUDE, latitude));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(
                    AndyConstants.Params.LONGITUDE, longitude));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(
                    AndyConstants.Params.BEARING, bearing + ""));
            preferenceHelper.putLatitude(Double.parseDouble(latitude));
            preferenceHelper.putLongitude(Double.parseDouble(longitude));

            postMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            String response = httpClient.execute(postMethod, res);
            // String response = httpRequest.postData(
            // AndyConstants.ServiceType.UPDATE_PROVIDER_LOCATION,
            // nameValuePairs);
            AppLog.Log("TAG", "location send Response:::" + response);

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            if (jsonObject.getBoolean("success")) {
                if (jsonObject.getString("is_active").equals("1"))
                    preferenceHelper.putIsActive(true);
                else
                    preferenceHelper.putIsActive(false);
            }

            return response;
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        stopSelf();
    }
}
```

Essa rotina fica no arquivo LocationUpdateService.java, esse arquivo envia para o servidor de tempos em tempos a localização do usuário (Latitude/Longitude).

Gostaria de contar com a ajuda de vocês para ter uma ideia pelo menos do que pode ser feito para resolver esse problema.

Comment: Se o problema esta no consumo do servidor, precisa analisar o servidor. Qual é a rotina do Laravel quando recebe esta chamada?

Answer (score 0):

Vou juntar algumas ideias para essa otimização aqui, afim de auxiliar ou iniciar o debate sobre alguma delas.

Acredito que não terá uma solução de massa de bolo nesse caso, vamos precisar testar.

1. Limitar o tempo de envio da requisição no APP

É possível enviar, por exemplo, uma requisição a cada dois segundos?

2. Verificar a configuração do webserver para entender se ele e esta mantendo o processo por muito tempo mesmo após concluir a requisição (isso mantem um consumo desnecessário)

O Apache/Nginx cria um processo para cada requisição, processo este que pode ser otimizado se você compreender melhor da necessidade da aplicação. Em outras palavras, um processo talvez não precise começar consumindo 20mb de memória, assim como ele talvez não precise ter um timeout muito alto. Mas ai estamos partindo para a otimização do webserver mesmo.

3. Testar o consumo 'unitario' da requisição, afim de torná-la mais enxuta

É possivel tornar o processo mais simples? Menos query, talvez um loop mais simples. Coisas essas que podem fazer o consumo ser menor.

Comment: Entendi, realmente são muitas possibilidades, mas o retorno da parte do servidor que tenho até então é que está ocorrendo muitas chamadas em sequencia da URL constante nessa rotina, nesse mesmo arquivo onde está essa rotina, mais abaixo a rotina é chamada conforme o código abaixo:

   if (preferenceHelper.getRequestId() == AndyConstants.NO_REQUEST) {

    isNoRequest = true;
    new UploadDataToServer().execute();
   } else {
    isNoRequest = false;
    new UploadTripLocationData().execute();
   }

Será que é possível limitar as chamadas nessa rotina? Se sim como recomendam fazer?

Comment: Mas ai que entra o pensar no que fazer, se a regra de negócio requer que as chamadas aconteçam dessa forma, precisará fazer algo para perfomatizar. Se não, precisamos limitar essas requisições para tornar o processo mais saudável.

Comment: Eu nao entendo de Java para te orientar, mas você pode fazer algo que valide se o tempo da ultima chamada é menor do que 2 segundos, por exemplo. Ou permitir as chamadas apenas em segundos (ou minutos) pares, algo assim.

Comment: É verdade, eu pensei mais ou menos algo nesse sentido, esperar algum tempo antes de chamar essas rotinas acima, tipo aguarda x tempo e ai chama a rotina, se tiver alguma ideia ajuda ai que toda ajuda é bem vida.

Valeu!

Abraço.

Comment: Então, o código que vc postou ainda é insuficiente pra fazer uma analise mais profunda do problema, como por exemplo, esta usa o FusedLocation para pegar a localização do dispositivo? Se não me engano tem uma opção de listener para pegar localização so quando o dispositivo estiver se locomovendo, e tem um limitador de tempo para execução, mas eu ainda acredito que o problema é a disponibilidade do servidor e o tratamento das requisições, no caso vc pode usar websocket o que resolveria esse problema de diversas requisições

Answer (score 0):

Também estou desenvolvendo um WS (RESTfull)

1. Verificar o seu servidor.
2. Verificar a maquina onde está o Servidor.
3. Faço teste unitário de 10 requisição/segundo.
4. Fracione seu tempo assim 100/1s, 100/0.5s, 100/0.25s até você pegar o estouro de pilha  (stack over flow ).
5. Pronto feito isso você agora sabe que se você sincronizar as req/s poderia atender muito bem milhares de requisiçães em um minuto.

**Obs:** Alguns Web Service como Américas.com Submarino Shoptime controlam acesso. Em 2014 na Black fraude milhares de pessoas ficaram na frente do pc por uns minutos em uma fila virtual na época eu não era programador mas eu entendia que aquilo era pra não derrubar ou até mesmo travar o site. Hoje eu sei por que fazer isso.  Resumo o problema não é atender 3600 requisições por minuto o problema é se elas forem recebida no último segundo do último minuto. Controle seu estouro de pilha.